# Understanding a concurrent modification exception

Tags: java

Why do I have a ConcurrentModificationException? I am iterating over the objects of a set and removing them in another set:

```
  public static void printSubsets(Set<String> set){
    if (set.isEmpty()) return;
    printSet(set);

    Set<String> copy = set;
    for (String s: set){
      copy.remove(s);
      printSubsets(copy);
      copy.add(s);
   }
  }
```

Comment: What do you think `Set<String> copy = set;` does and why?

Comment: *hint*, assignment != copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are removing them from the same `Set`, because there is only one `Set` object here.  You have 2 variables referring to the same `Set`, `set` and `copy`.

```
set -----> Set object
copy ------^
```

Any changes you make are visible through either variable.  You are removing elements from the `Set` while you're iterating over them with an enhanced for loop, so a `ConcurrentModificationException` results.

To prevent this, you can make a (shallow) copy of the set.

```
Set<String> copy = new HashSet<String>(set);
```